# Map in java - getting wrong map size

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how Map interface works in Java. What I am trying to do is: run through the array of strings and for each name in the array `name[]` put a random `grade`between 0 to 5. Then map the `grade`to `name[i]`. However, the map size gets weird, although I have 10 elements in array, the `map.size()`is 5 after mapping. Why does the program count the same size several times (see output)? Here is the code and output below:

```
    import java.util.*;  

    class MapInterfaceExample{  

    public static void main(String[] args){  

    int grade = 0; 
    String[] name = {"Lisa", "Dan", "John", "Adam", "George", "Amanda", "Sarah", "James", "Derek", "Sam"}; 

    Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  

    for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
    grade = (int)(Math.random()*5+1); 
    map.put(grade, name[i]);  
    //System.out.println(grade + "\t"+ name[i]);  
    System.out.println("Size of map "+ map.size());}
    } 
    }
```

Output:

Size of map 1

Size of map 2

Size of map 2

Size of map 2

Size of map 2

Size of map 3

Size of map 3

Size of map 4

Size of map 4

Size of map 5

Comment: Hint : Map won't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Are you sure the grades are the keys? If yes, do you want to collect al names with identical grades?

Comment: Check what kind of magic will happen if you  map.put(name[i],grade);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning a new value to the same key will override the old value, so if you have a maximum of 5 different keys (1-5) your map has a maximum size of 5.

You should use the name as the key, since they're unique. Then several students can have the same grade.

Comment: @Kayaman, ah thanks, I understand what is going on now. The size is triggered by the value I get from `grade`.

Comment: @Pshemo, how do I get 0-5? Thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo err yeah, of course.

Comment: @sumu00 Lets start with what you have now: `(int)(Math.random()*5+1);`. `Math.random()` can only generate value from range `[0;1)` (or lets write it as `[0; 0.9999999...]`). When we multiply it `5*[0;1)` it gives us new range `[0; 4.9999999...]`. After adding `+1` range becomes `[1; 5.99999999]`. By casting to `(int)` we remove `.999...` part so range is `[1; 5]`. If you want to get `[0; 5]` you can create range `[0; 5.9999....]` before casting. To generate such range you need `6*[0; 0.99999...]`. So value from such range can be generated using `int value = (int)(6*Math.random())`.

Comment: @Pshemo, such a good answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You use the grades as keys

```
map.put(grade, name[i]);
```

Since the range of grades is `[1, 5]`, the map will not become larger than 5.

Comment: thanks, now I figured out.